# Problem using Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I have installed Anaconda, but every time I open Terminal I have to go give the command:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Save the above command in your ~/.bashrc file and after that reload .bashrc file by using source ~/.bashrc command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make sure that command is executed for every terminal (meaning Anaconda will be found) by adding it to your user's **bash profile**.

Open a terminal and follow these steps:

1. open the terminal profile: `gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. at the end of the file, add: `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`
3. save the file (`control+s`) and close it
4. load the changed profile: `source ~/.bashrc`

Now this terminal window (and any **new** ones) should find Anaconda! See which version of Python is now the default, using `which -a python`. First in the list should be something like `/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python`

The Anaconda setup/installation usually asks you if you want to prepend Anaconda to start of your path, so whoever installed it must have said no or skipped that step.

Answer (score 2):

Write your command in your `.bashrc`  (access at  `~/.bashrc` )

It will be executed each time you call a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

the file .bashrc (hidden file), located in the home directory, runs codes every time a new terminal is opened.
Then add a line on it:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Some other solutions are also provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path).